# Struts2 plugin Netbeans

Tags: struts2

I need to Develop Web Application using JSPs and Servlet.Therefore I have to Add the Struts2 on the Netbeans.can anyone Help me to add the Struts2 plugin on the Netbeans.I am currently Using Netbeans 6.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add support for a specific framework by installing the appropriate framework support plugin into the IDE. To do so, you can either download the plugin modules from an external site such as the NetBeans Plugin Portal then install the plugin via the Plugins Manager, or, if the plugin is maintained by an update center, you can register the update center with the IDE's Plugins Manager and then download and install the plugin directly through the Plugins Manager.

Please go through this page for details as how to download and install Struuts2 plugin for netBeans

1. [framework-adding-support](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/framework-adding-support.html)
2. [netbeans-struts2-support](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/23467/netbeans-struts2-support)

Comment: if it solve your problem, you can mark the answer as accepted, so if some one other has same isssue can use answer as a reference.

Comment: He could also just create a maven web project and follow the guide on the struts2 site...

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi: The JAR files `(lib)` of the plugin are downloaded via internet? As NetbeansSupport just sent 3 `.nbm` files, it makes me wonder whether the `.nbm` files act as a package for the libraries? Please throw some light on this.